GlobalID errors after Rails downgrade like "incompatible marshal file format (can't be read) (TypeError) format version 4.8 required; 34.103 given"
After upgrading to Rails 7.1 and then rolling back to Rails 7.0, we saw errors like

incompatible marshal file format (can't be read) (TypeError)
format version 4.8 required; 34.103 given

when running code like
GlobalID::Locator.locate_signed(my_gid, for: "somename")

with a my_gid that was set on Rails 7.1.
What could the issue be?

Our findings were that this happens when a MessageVerifier in Rails 7.0, configured to use Marshal serialization, gets data serialized by Rails 7.1 with the JSON serializer.
The "34.103 given" part is confusing, but is actually the first two ASCII codes of the JSON data. So it corresponds to "g in this case, where the serialized data was a "gid://…" string. (Serialized JSON data can be just a string; doesn't need to be an {} object.)
Our fix consisted of two steps:

In our Rails 7.0 app, add a "rotator", telling MessageVerifier to try JSON deserialization if Marshal fails.
A monkeypatch to make Rails 7.0 actually fall back if Marshal fails – it sadly doesn't. (This was fixed in Rails 7.1.)

In our case, we only saw this issue with a use of GlobalID::Locator, so we put it in config/initializers/global_id.rb and only added a rotator there. You may need to add it elsewhere for other situations – if so, please comment.
if Rails.version < Gem::Version.new("7.1")
  module ActiveSupport
    class MessageVerifier
      def verified(signed_message, purpose: nil, **)
        data, digest = get_data_and_digest_from(signed_message)
        if digest_matches_data?(digest, data)
          begin
            message = Messages::Metadata.verify(decode(data), purpose)
            @serializer.load(message) if message
          rescue ArgumentError => argument_error
            return if argument_error.message.include?("invalid base64")
            raise
          # Monkeypatch: start
          rescue TypeError => e
            return if e.message.include?("incompatible marshal file format")
            raise
          # Monkeypatch: end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
    SignedGlobalID.verifier.rotate(serializer: JSON)
  end
end


A tip for cleaner monkeypatching is to write a module (somewhere else) and include it in the initializer instead of reopening the class. https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/#:~:text=If%20you%20keep%20your%20patches,safe%20as%20they%20can%20be.

We considered modules, but the tricky thing here is that there is a prepended module providing rotations and calling super to get at the now-monkeypatched code. We wanted this code to go “over” the place we patched but “under” that prepended module. Alias method chaining would have worked. Didn’t feel worth further effort for short-lived downgrade compatibility, but I agree in principle and will normally use modules.
